# Css - how to select the first of type on page

Tags: css, css-selectors

Most of my pages have H2's and obviously an H1.

The H2's can be inside divs/articles/sections etc - in other words there is no guaranteed structure.

Here's a typical scenario:

```
<h1></h1>
<section>
    <h2>I want this one</h2>
    <p></p>
</section>
<section>
    <h2>But not this one</h2>
    <p></p>
</section>
```

I want a selector that always guarantees the first occurance on the page - in this case the first H2 wherever it maybe.

I've taken a look and tried the first-of-type selector but found that it applies to its own container, so every H2 is selected here because it is the first within its parent section tag.

Surely in 2015, we are able to do this.

Comment: I am not sure that there a selector with the functionality you seek exists, but you could use the the first-of-type selector if all of your `<h2>` exist inside `<section>`. Would that work for you?

Comment: They do in this scenario, but I would have to map a selector specifically for every page variation where the structure differed, so not exactly efficient css.

Comment: @JohnOhara I think that Javascript would be your best bet here, I can't think of a way to do this via CSS only.

Comment: "Surely in 2015, we are able to do this."...Nope...Javascript is the **only** solution in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery. Honestly i tried css only methods, but failed. Excellent question btw.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "h2:first" ).css( "color", "red" );
});

</script>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('h2')` for non-jQuery solution :)

Answer (score -1):

you could simply use the css selector `first-of-type`

> Definition and Usage The :first-of-type selector matches every element
>   that is the first child, of a particular type, of its parent.
>
> Tip: This is the same as :nth-of-type(1).

```
h2:first-of-type {
    color: red;
}
```

or as a jQuery solution:

```
$('h2').first().css('color','red');
```

Comment: Once again, read the question. Look at my other comments if you need more help understanding the question. And the user has not asked for a jQuery solution.

Comment: the jquery solution is exactly what you need..

Comment: I am not the OP and the OP did not ask for a jQuery solution otherwise they would have tagged it on the question or edited the question.

Comment: well but he did not say that he needs it in css only.. it's not possible in css only imo.

Comment: first-of-type would not work in this situation, as outlined in the question.